# how to run qtcreator on linux? 2 versions installed

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qt-creator

I had qt 4.8.0 installed on Ubuntu.
It's qtcreator executable is in /usr/bin/ and this version runs when I type 'qtcreator' in terminal.
Then I've installed qt 5.2.0 in my home directory.
I don't know how to run it.

Comment: try `ls ~/.local/share/applications/` to see if there is something in there

Comment: also you should specify what kind of installation you just performed : netinst or offline ?

Answer (score 2):

Most simple way to install qt creator on linux is :
Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install qtcreator`
or
Fedora: `yum install qtcreator`
it runs perfectly using command `qtcreator`
it may return some of the openGL warnings but it shoulden't matter as far as your program runs.

Answer (score 1):

To run it you can simply stay in your home directory and execute it as ./qtcreator

Now if you want to execute as the same way as the another version you can put a soft link en usr/bin to qtcreator of the version you want.